# AHK WinMaximize not working properly

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey

Im writing a script in AutoHotkey that is supposed to place a window that gets opened to a certain monitor (this setup has 3 monitors in a an L shape flipped over the vertical axis). The window gets moved to the correct monitor, but for some reason, the window doesnt maximize. When I click the maximize icon in the upper right, it maximizes as it normally should, but for some reason the script wont maximize it. I have gotten other windows to maximize using the line "WinMaximize" but for some reason I can not get this certain window to maximize. My Code is below

```
WinWait, Alarms
    WinActivate                                         ;Activate Window
    WinGetPos, Xpos, Ypos                               ;Get Window Position
    XPosPlus:=(Xpos + 1920)                             ;Get Monitor 3 X coord
    YPosPlus:=(Ypos - 1080)                             ;Get Monitor 3 Y coord
    WinMove, %XPosPlus%, %YPosPlus%                     ;Move window to monitor 3
    WinMaximize                                        ;Maximize Window
    Send {tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}A{space}    ;Enter A into the proper textbox
    ExitApp                                             ;Close Script
```

Is this a bug in auto hotkey? Or perhaps there is a Windows setting pertaining to this window specifically?

### Things I've tried

-Looping WinMaximize for 3 or 4 times

-Maximizing before I perform WinMove

-Maximizing the window and doing nothing else

None of this actually maximizes the window.

Comment: Try setting all coordinates (x,y,w,h) with just [WinMove](http://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinMove.htm) instead of WinMove+WinMaximize.

Comment: @wOxxOm I just attempted to resize it with winmove also, at a variety of different sizes and it would not resize. Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 3):

Some windows (border types) don't respond well to WinMax.  Does it work on your primary monitor?  I guess not . . .

Oh well, you will need to look into `WinSet, Style, 0x40000` and probably followed by `WinSet, Redraw` and you should look at the help on these commands (see below) for important limitations and workarounds:

```
WinWait, Alarms
    WinActivate                                         ;Activate Window

    WinSet, Style, 0x40000                              ;Apply sizing border
    WinSet, Reraw                                       ;Redraw window with sizing border

    WinGetPos, Xpos, Ypos                               ;Get Window Position
    XPosPlus:=(Xpos + 1920)                             ;Get Monitor 3 X coord
    YPosPlus:=(Ypos - 1080)                             ;Get Monitor 3 Y coord
    WinMove, %XPosPlus%, %YPosPlus%                     ;Move window to monitor 3
    WinMaximize                                         ;Maximize Window
    Send {tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}{tab}A{space}    ;Enter A into the proper textbox
    ExitApp                                             ;Close Script
```

Check out https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm

Hth

Answer (score 1):

Changing the border didnt work and made the window unusable. It turns out that the window would open in the same location every time so i wrote a line that would click on the maximize icon rather than having it do it behind the scenes. This made my script work